# Search for blank lines in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, regular-expressions

I have a lot of code lines, written in TeXstudio. Now I realized that I sometimes forgot to add a blank space after the `\[...\]` math mode. So I wanted to search&replace

```
\[
...
\]
Here is the text
```

with

```
\[
...
\]

Here is the text
```

But I cannot find a regular expression for a blank line.
How can I do that?

Comment: Why would you always have a blank like after displayed math? That is not common. Usually a newline is `\n`.

Comment: @daleif But if I search for \n, I only get results like \newcommand.

Comment: You need to enable regular expressions. The button has `.*` on it, I believe. But what are you trying to do? A blank line ends a paragraph. But paragraphs don't have to end after display math.

Comment: Isn't your description backwards then? If you are looking for the second example and want to make it into the first? There are no blank lines in the first example (do remember that a blank line has two line breaks and may contain spaces in between.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel it is activated. The button is "reg". But searching for \n results in nothing, although there are a lot of blank lines.

Comment: @daleif Well, I thought whether I want to search for blank lines or insert a blank line via regexp was no difference.

Comment: I'm not sure that the regex search in texstudio is powerful enough. At least it does not seem to support \n.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1369/

Comment: For me, the button is `.*` (v4.5.1, Windows). [This discussion seems to relevant.](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907839/thread/5e78776f/). End of line is `$` but it doesn't look like TeXstudio can insert linebreaks when replacing. Maybe use another editor.

Comment: Sorry to put it so bluntly, but what you want to do seems wrong. Usually a displayed maths environment is part of a paragraph, but seldomly ends it. The cases in which it actually ends a paragraph should be pretty rare, and you shouldn't generalise it to always end a paragraph! So in this case, it seems good that TeXstudio's search&replace is not capable of doing this...